# Price loading only when reopen the activity or when click on buy button

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing

Prices are not shown to the user at first, need to reopen the activity several times to show the price or click on buy button.

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()

        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                if (billingResult.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_1)
                    getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_2)
                    getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_3)
                    getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_4)
                }
            }
}
```

and function getPrice:

```
private fun getPrice(productId: String) {

        // Define the product details to query
        val productList =
            listOf(
                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(productId)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build(),
            )

        // Create query parameters
        val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList).build()

        // Query product details
        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                if (productDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    // Extract the product details
                    val productDetails = productDetailsList[0]

                    // Get the price of the product
                    val price = productDetails.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails?.formattedPrice

                    // Update the corresponding TextView with the price
                    when (productId) {
                        PRODUCT_ID_1 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price1).text = price
                        PRODUCT_ID_2 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price2).text = price
                        PRODUCT_ID_3 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price3).text = price
                        PRODUCT_ID_4 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price4).text = price
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why the textviews with price usually not show the values? It only gets when I reopen activity or click in buy button (that will run the launchBillingFlow).

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering, where the prices are not shown to the user until the activity is reopened or the buy button is clicked, is likely due to the asynchronous nature of the billing queries. In your code, you're using the `BillingClient` to query product details asynchronously, and the updates to the `TextViews` are happening when the queries are completed.

To ensure that the prices are shown to the user when the activity starts, you should move the code that updates the `TextViews` with prices to the `onBillingSetupFinished` callback. This ensures that the prices are fetched and displayed when the billing client is set up. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
    .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
    .enablePendingPurchases()
    .build()

billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            // Query and display prices when billing setup is finished
            getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_1)
            getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_2)
            getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_3)
            getPrice(PRODUCT_ID_4)
        }
    }
})

// Remove getPrice calls from here

private fun getPrice(productId: String) {
    // Define the product details to query
    val productList =
        listOf(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductId(productId)
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                .build(),
        )

    // Create query parameters
    val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList).build()

    // Query product details
    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            if (productDetailsList.size > 0) {
                // Extract the product details
                val productDetails = productDetailsList[0]

                // Get the price of the product
                val price = productDetails.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails?.formattedPrice

                // Update the corresponding TextView with the price
                when (productId) {
                    PRODUCT_ID_1 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price1).text = price
                    PRODUCT_ID_2 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price2).text = price
                    PRODUCT_ID_3 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price3).text = price
                    PRODUCT_ID_4 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price4).text = price
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By moving the `getPrice` calls to the `onBillingSetupFinished` callback, you ensure that the prices are fetched and displayed as soon as the billing client is set up, rather than relying on user interactions to trigger the queries. This should resolve the issue of prices not being displayed until the activity is reopened or the buy button is clicked.